# How to convert FText to float in UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm getting user input from a box in the unreal engine landscape import pane and would like to be able to convert that input to a float. Currently, the text comes in as `FText`

I've tried casting the resulting `FText` to float and using the built-in `FText::toNumber`.

I would like to be able to do something like:

```cpp
FText mapDeltaX = GetPropertyValueText(PropertyHandle_Scale_X);
float deltaX = (float)mapDeltaX;
```

But unfortunately I get the error `no suitable conversion from "FText" to "float" exists`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert TCHAR* to float using

```
FCString::Atof(*String);
```

So in your case you'd convert your FText to FString, then to float:

```
FCString::Atof(*mapDeltaX.ToString());
```